# How to Listen for Upload Finished with jQuery in WordPress Thickbox Upload Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm injecting some jQuery to make the Alt Text field required in WordPress upload thick box.

It intercepts the ***Insert into Post*** button click and checks if the field has been filled or not.

It works ok for the ***Gallery*** and ***Media Library*** tabs, but the ***From Computer*** tab needs a needs a "*listener*" when an upload finishes to alter the behavior of the ***Insert into Post*** button.

[image]

---

---

I was trying with `setInterval`, but don't know how to *kill* or *recreate* it, but maybe someone is aware if a listener exists, or even how to make this code work because I suspect my logic here is fuzzy...

Here's the code, commented.

```
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup','so_11149675_required_alt_text');

function so_11149675_required_alt_text()
{
    // Detect current tab ("From Computer" == "type")
    $tab = isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] : "type";

    // ( 'From Computer' or ( 'Gallery' and 'Library' ) )
    $jquery = ('type' == $tab) ? 'var refreshUpload = setInterval(function(){$(".savesend input").each(checkAltTextPermanent);},500);' : '$(".savesend input").each(checkAltTextOnce);';

    echo <<<HTML
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        // var refreshUpload; /* testing */

        // Function called by From Computer tab
        // should run only once -> when the upload table and fields are created
        function checkAltTextPermanent() {
            // Create the required asterisk symbol
            // setInterval creates a loop here
            jQuery('.image_alt th label').each(function(i,e) {
                jQuery('<span class="alignright"><abbr title="required" class="required">*</abbr></span>').prependTo(this);
            }); 

            // Alter button behavior
            // Another loop in the alert box
            jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
                // clearInterval(refreshUpload);
                var value = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.image_alt input').val();

                if('' != value) 
                    return true;

                alert ('Please fill the Alt text');
                return false;
            });
        }

        // Function called by Gallery and Library tabs
        function checkAltTextOnce() {
            jQuery(this).click(function(e) {
                var value = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.image_alt input').val();

                if('' != value) 
                    return true;

                alert ('Please fill the Alt text');
                return false;
            });
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Defined in PHP, calls checkAltTextOnce or checkAltTextPermanent
            {$jquery}

            // Used in Gallery and Libray tabs
            $('.image_alt th label').each(function(i,e) {
                $('<span class="alignright"><abbr title="required" class="required">*</abbr></span>').prependTo(this);
            });
        });
    </script>
HTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(".savesend input").live("click", validateAltText);

function validateAltText() {
    var value = $(".image_alt input").val();

    if (value) 
        return true;

    alert('Please fill the Alt text');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As soon as a file is uploaded the `.image_alt` is created in the ThickBox. In this moment I need to add the `click()` listener in the `input button`. I tried to wrap your code in the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...});` but didn't worked... Thanks for the input.

Comment: Ah, I think that is because the method was invoking itself. Try again with edit.

Comment: Maybe the misunderstanding lies in when the validation should fire. The code above will validate the text if the user clicks the close button at the top right of the dialog box, or if the user clicks in the background somewhere to close it.

Comment: David, as I said in my question `$(".submit .savesend input")` **does not exist** when jQuery Document is Ready... Your code only works for DOM elements already existent, not for the ones created **after** a file is uploaded...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12887/discussion-between-davidkennedy85-and-brasofilo)